# How to scrape data from website having "View More" option using BeautifulSoup library in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse comments from this website link :
[I need to get 1000 comments, by default it shows only 10](https://www.mygov.in/group-issue/share-your-ideas-pm-narendra-modis-mann-ki-baat-26th-march-2017/)

I want to get 1000 comments, it shows only 10 by default. I am unable to figure out a way to get the content which shows on the webpage after clicking 'View More'

I have the following code uptil now:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.mygov.in/group-issue/share-
your-ideas-pm-narendra-modis-mann-ki-baat-26th-march-2017/")

srcode = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(srcode, "html.parser")

all_comments_div=soup.find_all('div', class_="comment_body");

all_comments=[]
for div in all_comments_div:
    all_comments.append(div.find('p').text.translate(non_bmp_map))



print (all_comments)
print (len(all_comments))
```

Comment: How are you trying to click "View More"... selenium, or are you grabbing the "next" href and requesting that page directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop to get the next pages
( ie while there is a next page and all comments are less than 1000 )

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
all_comments = [] 
max_comments = 1000
base_url = 'https://www.mygov.in/'
next_page = base_url + '/group-issue/share-your-ideas-pm-narendra-modis-mann-ki-baat-26th-march-2017/'

while next_page and len(all_comments) < max_comments : 
    response = response = urllib.request.urlopen(next_page)
    srcode = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(srcode, "html.parser")

    all_comments_div=soup.find_all('div', class_="comment_body");
    for div in all_comments_div:
        all_comments.append(div.find('p').text.translate(non_bmp_map))

    next_page = soup.find('li', class_='pager-next first last')
    if next_page : 
        next_page = base_url + next_page.find('a').get('href')
    print('comments: {}'.format(len(all_comments)))

print(all_comments)
print(len(all_comments))
```

Answer (score 1):

The new comments are loaded via `ajax`, we need to parse it and then use `bs`, i.e.:

```
import json
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

how_many_pages = 5 # how many comments pages you want to parse?
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
all_comments = []

for x in range(how_many_pages):
    # note: mygov.in seems very slow...
    json_data = requests.get(
        "https://www.mygov.in/views/ajax/?view_name=view_comments&view_display_id=block_2&view_args=267721&view_path=node%2\
F267721&view_base_path=comment_pdf_export&view_dom_id=f3a7ae636cabc2c47a14cebc954a2ff0&pager_element=1&sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&page=0,{}"\
            .format(x)).content
    d = json.loads(json_data.decode()) # Remove .decode() for python < 3
    print(len(d))
    if len(d) == 3: # sometimes json lenght is 3 
        comments = d[2]['data'] # data is the key that contains the comments html
    elif len(d) == 2: # others just 2...
        comments = d[1]['data']

    #From here, we can use your BeautifulSoup code.  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comments, "html.parser")
    all_comments_div = soup.find_all('div', class_="comment_body");

    for div in all_comments_div:
        all_comments.append(div.find('p').text.translate(non_bmp_map))


print(all_comments)
```

---

**Output**:

```
["Sir my humble submission is that please ask public not to man handle doctors because they work in a very delicate situation, to save a patient is not always in his hand. The incidents of manhandling doctors is increasing day by day and it's becoming very difficult to work in these situatons. Majority are not Opting for medical profession,...']
```